# rvg and officer giving "filled in" font for PowerPoint editable vector graphic element

Tags: r, ggplot2, officer, showtext, rvg

We can make a `ggplot` object and change its font with the `showtext` package.

```
library(ggplot2)
library(showtext)
library(officer)
library(rvg)

p1 <- ggplot(mtcars, aes(x = cyl)) + 
  geom_bar() +
  ggtitle("A B C D")

font_add_google("Poppins")
showtext_auto()
p2 <- p1 + theme(text = element_text(family = "Poppins"))
```

This yields an image that looks as expected.
[image: ggplot_image]

Yet, if I next use the `officer` and `rvg` packages to print the same plot
as an **editable vector graphics element** within a .pptx file, something goes awry.

```
pptx <- read_pptx()
pptx <- add_slide(pptx,  layout = "Blank", master = "Office Theme")
pptx <- ph_with(x = pptx, value = dml(ggobj = p2), location = ph_location(width=6, height=6))
print(pptx, target = "Slide_ABCD.pptx")
```

The characters in the plot end up being "filled in". This problem does not appear when you use the default `ggplot2` fonts.
[image]

The `?rvg::dml` documentation says this about the `fonts` argument:

> Named list of font names to be aliased with fonts installed on your
> system. If unspecified, the R default families sans, serif, mono and
> symbol are aliased to the family returned by match_family().
>
> When you use specific fonts, you will need that font installed on your
> system. This can be check with package gdtools and function
> gdtools::font_family_exists().

When I run `gdtools::font_family_exists("Poppins")`, it returns TRUE

I've tried to specify "Poppins" and "Poppins-Regular" in the `rvg:dml()` call, like this:

```
pptx <- ph_with(x = pptx, value = dml(ggobj = p2, fonts = list(sans = "Poppins", serif = "Poppins", mono = "Poppins")), location = ph_location(width=6, height=6))
```

But these steps don't change the output. I still get "filled in" font.

I am aware that one can insert an image file into these pptx outputs, but I really need the output to be an **editable vector graphics element**.

Any ideas for how I can fix this problem so the **editable vector graphics element** font looks like the image font?

Comment: Does it change something if you additionally load `library(sysfonts)`?

Comment: Thanks. I just tried loading `library(sysfonts)` at the top of my code, but its execution did not change the "filled in" font output.

Answer (score 0):

My solution to the "filled text" problem is to use the `extrafont` package, instead of `showtext`.

Once the font is imported and loaded, it is rendered correctly in the ggplot and
in the editable vector graphics element.

````
# only need to be done once!!!
extrafont::font_import(pattern = "Poppins-Regular.ttf")

# do this in each session
extrafont::loadfonts()

p2 <- p1 + theme(text = element_text(family = "Poppins"))

pptx <- read_pptx()
pptx <- add_slide(pptx,  layout = "Blank", master = "Office Theme")
pptx <- ph_with(x = pptx, 
                value = dml(ggobj = p2), 
                location = ph_location(width=6, height=6))

print(pptx, target = "Slide_ABCD.pptx")
```
````